# Vanilla Javascript Disable Button After Click With LocalStorage For X Seconds Then Enable Button Again

Tags: javascript, local-storage, spam-prevention

How do you do something like this in vanilla javascript and not jQuery?

1. Click button which submits a form which refreshes/redirects to the same page
2. Button is disabled after clicked when the page refreshes
3. localStorage stores the disabled button for X seconds
4. After X seconds pass, enable the disabled button again
5. Repeat this process again if the user clicks the button again

Answer (score 1):

Can't make a snippet since stackoverlow won't allow access to localStorage but:

```
<form onsubmit="handleSubmit(event)">
    <input type="text" id="target" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
<script>

  let disable = localStorage.getItem("disable");

  if(disable){
    console.log("5 second timeout");
    setTimeout(()=> {
      localStorage.removeItem("disable");
      disable = false;
      console.log("button enabled");
    },5000);
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(disable){
      console.log("button is disabled"); 
      return;
    }
    localStorage.setItem("disable",true);
    location.reload();    
  }

</script>
```

Edit: Something like the below would modify it for a specific button

```
function handlerWrapper(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(disable){
      console.log("button is disabled"); 
      return;
    }
    yourActualHandler(e); 
    localStorage.setItem("disable",true);
    location.reload();    
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is there a way to do it without inline javascript  onsubmit="handleSubmit(event)" to follow content security policy? Maybe access the specific button ID? Codepen and other javascript shareable links should have access to localStorage. Otherwise I will test it and let you know how it goes.

Comment: it's a cross origin issue because of the sandbox so they intentionally don't allow it

Comment: Your code is useful for just having one button in the form, so it may help people so it can stay. But it uses inline javascript which is bad for content security policy. What if you have multiple buttons in the form but only wish to disable a specific one? When I tried your code for my use case with multiple button tags of type submit (not input tags), my form could not be submitted during the first click. But it did add to localStorage and the button could not be clicked for 5 seconds which was good. Maybe add onto your answer this type of use case also.

Comment: It doesn't need to be inline; that was so you could copy and run it easier. To target a single button, you'd pass that button a wrapper function which executes the above, but then also calls your intended function after the conditional.

Comment: Ok thanks for the edit and explanation! I will give it a try and let you know how it goes!

Comment: You may need to apply some configuration to make it async for your specific code, but the general idea is there.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the `localStorage` API you mentioned, all you need are the `disabled` attribute on the button and the `setTimeout` method on the window object.

See the in-code comments for further explanation.

(Note: Code that uses `localStorage` cannot run in SO snippets due to sandboxing, but you can save it as an html file in your text editor if you want to see it running.)

```
<button id="refresh">Refresh</button>
<script>
  const refreshBtn = document.getElementById("refresh");
  refreshBtn.addEventListener("click", refresh);
  disable();

  function disable() {
    // If `disableRefresh` is truthy...
    if (localStorage.getItem("disableRefresh")) {
      // ...Disables the button and re-enables it after 2 seconds
      refreshBtn.setAttribute("disabled", ""); // Any value makes it true
      setTimeout(enable, 2000); // JavaScript measures times in milliseconds
    }
  }

  function enable() {
    // Removes (boolean) `disabled` attribute and (string) `disableRefresh` item
    refreshBtn.removeAttribute("disabled");
    localStorage.removeItem("disableRefresh")
  }

  function refresh() {
    // Sets `disableRefresh` to a truthy value, and refreshes the page
    localStorage.setItem("disableRefresh", "yep");
    location = location;
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work well! I just thought that it did not work because the seconds are too low. Increasing them worked. However, one issue I have is that the user still could spam click during the first button click while the button action is still processing. Is there a way to disable the button right after first click while the form is processing also while keeping the rest of your functionality?

Comment: Sure, you would just add `refreshBtn.setAttribute("disabled", "");` as the very first line in the body of the `refresh` function ... so when the button is clicked, it immediately becomes disabled.

Comment: Although that works, the button does not finish processing the action, causing the button not to serve its primary purpose.

Comment: Oh, I see your point. What if you just put it at the bottom of the `refresh` function then?

Comment: The button action still does not process even if you put it at the bottom of the refresh function.

Comment: Nevermind I think I figured it out. I added the CSS from this page and then used var btn = document.querySelector('#refresh'); btn.classList.add('disabled'); to the beginning of the refresh function. https://gomakethings.com/dont-disable-buttons-while-submitting-forms-with-ajax/ unless you have a better way?

Comment: I tested the script with `refreshBtn.setAttribute("disabled", "");` at the top of the `refresh function`. I edited the answer to include this revision as well as a line that prints a random number when the page loads (which "proves" that the button is still doing its job -- at least when I tested it in Chrome in Windows 10). I also increased the delay to 4 seconds. However, if this version is failing for some reason in any browser that you're targeting, then using the two lines you added (in your comment) may be a better option.

Comment: Just tried your new one. The button processes the action but the disabling and localStorage no longer work. Unless you want to fix it, I think reverting back to your original answer would be best and if someone wanted to use the CSS technique I found they could use that also.

Comment: Okay, cool. The revised answer seemed to work for me, but I'll revert to the one you found more useful in case others would run into the same issue.

Comment: No worries. I had no idea you could actually click the edit code and see revisions. So if somebody needs to work off your solution they should click the edit button. Thanks for all the help with this! You led me to an answer I was looking for :)

Comment: I noticed that the user needs to stay on the page for however long the setTimeout lasts in order for the button to enable itself again. Is there a way for the timer / localStorage key/value to expire so that the button enables itself again without the user needing to stay on that page for the entire time?

Comment: I worked on this but haven't gotten back to it. For now: yes, and the trick is to use a JS Date object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). I'd 1)Use the `.getTime()` method to get a timestamp (in milliseconds), 2)Pick an "expiration" time X seconds in the future by adding X*1000 to it, and 3)Store the resulting number as `localStorage.enableAt` (where it's actually stored as a string!). Then when the page loads (and maybe once per second afterward) if the button is disabled, make a new Date object and compare its timestamp to the stored one.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable approach. I hope that you get back to it soon. I am looking forward to how you will implement this!